# Heroku Django error: SSL certificate has expired

Tags: python, django, heroku

How do I make my free Heroku site work? I did not change it from the time it was working to when it stopped working.

[site](https://moresomervillehappinessapp.herokuapp.com/home)
[code](https://github.com/DavidSmolinski/portfolio/tree/master/websites/msh)

When I opened my site, I got an "Application Error" page. I followed its instructions. I ran the Heroku CLI command "heroku logs --tail" and got an error. I then ran "heroku logs --tail --app moresomervillehappinessapp".

Here are the last logs:

```
2020-04-06T20:49:47.204222+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
2020-04-06T20:49:47.204222+00:00 app[web.1]: raise URLError(err)
2020-04-06T20:49:47.204228+00:00 app[web.1]: urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)>
```

According to Heroku, I can use the "*.herokuapp.com" certificate for SSL. Should I try to get rid of the SSL certificate? I care a little bit about SEO, but not the security of user data.

Software I used: Django 3.0.2, Python 3.8

Comment: This looks like an issue with some _other_ site that your code is trying to communicate with. Do you make any HTTPS / API requests in your appplication?

Comment: You are probably right. My site reads a csv from a site that switched their url from https to http. I will delete "https://" from that url in my code. If their link fails, I can host the csv or a pickled model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My site used an URL to read a CSV from a university site. The URL had "https:" in it. Now it has "http:". I put the CSV on Github and changed the URL my site reads.